# Need to add underscore to my regex

Tags: regex

I'm new to regular expression and just can't seem to figure this out:

```
'/^[A-Za-z0-9](?:.[A-Za-z0-9]+)$/'
```

As it's right now it allows dots anytime after the first char and I like to add `_` so that it allows both.
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, `/^[A-Za-z0-9](?:.[A-Za-z0-9]+)$/` allows any character after the first letter, since `.` is a special character matching anything.

Use

`/^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[._][A-Za-z0-9]+)$/`

Inside character classes (denoted by the sqaure brackets), the dot loses its special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]*(?:[._][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/
```

In your present state regex would allow any character (including dot).

Answer (score 0):

```
 '/^[A-Za-z0-9](?:.[A-Za-z0-9_]+)$/'
```

I hope this helps